# position:relative; of navbar seems to be stopping body from showing

Tags: html, css, nav

I am making a website portfolio which will assist when applying for a year in industry as part of my computer science degree. I've designed my site on paper before creating it, and my navbar/logo show up exactly as intended, however I am using position:relative; which seems to be preventing my heading1 to be displayed, I have attached a JSFiddle of what I have so far, could someone point in the correct direction to get this to work? I appreciate all help, thank you!

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/kv65vw34/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled the `position`

```
#tag {
    postion:absolute; // it should be position
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! typos happen to the best of us... right?